# Can't use FileSystemWatcher in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, filesystemwatcher

I am new to Visual Studio and C#.  I am used to using XCode and Objective-C but am now trying to write a Windows 8 app.  I am trying to set up a `FileSystemWatcher` when the user clicks a button in my app, but for some reason Visual Studio refuses to recognize that I can do it and throws an error.  Here is a sample of what I have written:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
...

namespace My_APP
{
...
    public sealed partial class MainPage : My_App.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
    ...
        public void button_click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
        }
    }
}
```

The `FileSystemWatcher` is underlined both times in red with the error: `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'FileSystemWatcher' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  What am I doing wrong (I'm sure it is something incredibly simple).

Comment: Because `FileSystemWatcher` is not included in the version of .NET used for Windows 8 apps. If it was supported you would see ".NET for Windows Store apps, Supported in: Windows 8" in the Version Information section of the MSDN page.

Comment: I wonder if this may be because you're trying to build a Metro app, and the FileSystemWatcher requires full-trust.  I thought there was some bits to the security model that prevented the apps from running in FullTrust mode.

Comment: @mikez you might as well add that as an answer, as that's what the OP is facing.  Windows Store apps use a completely different API, which is all asynchronous and has restricted access to resources.  If you know of an alternative (doubt there is one) you can suggest.

Comment: @Will Right. Personally, I didn't consider it an "answer" because I could not provide any suggestions or alternatives.

Comment: @mikez "No" with an explanation is as good as answer as any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `FileSystemWatcher` is not included in the version of .NET used for Windows 8 apps. If it was supported you would see ".NET for Windows Store apps, Supported in: Windows 8" in the Version Information section of the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). Contrast this with `BinaryReader` which is [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx).

The Windows.Storage [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx) has the APIs for file system access in Windows 8 apps.

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

To get notified when files or folders get created, modified or deleted, you can use the classes `Windows.Storage.Search.StorageFolderQueryResult` and `Windows.Storage.Search.StorageFileQueryResult`, and the `ContentsChanged` event.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefilequeryresult.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefolderqueryresult.aspx

Comment: I believe you correct. However, I cannot get ContentsChanged to fire reliably. That seems a common problem.